# Macro for Searching large database for Assembly number, pasting results in another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA coding, but I basically wanted create a similar function to this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxhRSCfHaw

I have two sheets of interest, Stencils and Search. I'd like to be able to type the assembly number into the Search tab, press a macro button, have it search through the Stencils tab and paste the data it finds matching the assembly number. Possibly I might need to change how I define my variables, not sure.

I can run the code without any errors. The code clears the contents of the destination cells as it should. However, it does not paste anything.

```
Sub findstencil()

'1. declare variables
'2. clear old search results
'3. find records that match search criteria and paste them


Dim assembly As String 'Assembly number of interest, containts numbers, letters and dashes
Dim finalrow As Integer 'determines last row in database
Dim i As Integer 'row counter


'clears destination cells
Sheets("Search").Range("A7:H15").ClearContents



assembly = Sheets("Search").Range("A5").Value
finalrow = Sheets("Stencils").Range("C5000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 8) = assembly Then
        Sheets("Stencils").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 8)).Copy
        Sheets("Search").Range("B15").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

Next i

Sheets("Search").Range("A5").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: `it isn't working` - very vague. Please read [How to Create a Complete, Minimal and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future reference. What is not working about it? Does it error? Does it not produce what you want? Have you stepped through the code line-by-line to see what each line is doing compared to what you expect? Lastly `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats` may not be what you need. You might try `xlPasteValues`. One more note. `assembly` can be defined as `String`. Will save memory.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help, but I got a code working that does kinda what you need [on CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/176710/match-contents-of-two-sheets-put-it-on-a-third-sheet). @ScottHoltzman, Is it against the rules to do this?

Comment: @Moacir - adding a comment with a possible link that can help is surely okay. If it turns out not to help, you can always delete. However, looking at the question you wrote on CR, it doesn't really look like a good candidate for that site.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman The code doesn't produce what I want- it doesn't paste anything. However, it does clear the contents of the destination cells as it should. I edited my original post with your suggestions for a verifiable example. I changed to xlPasteValues as you suggested and changed assembly to String. I'll keep stepping through line by line to see if I can identify anything else.

Comment: @Mcodewick - Change `If Cells(i, 8)` to `If Sheets("Stencils").Cells(i, 8)`. Leaving `Cells` unqualified against an object automatically assigns it to whatever sheet is active at Run-Time, which may not be the one you think it is.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks, I think we're getting closer to the solution now. I made this change- but now when I run it, I get a Run time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method. This is referring to:  Sheets("Search").Range("B15").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: @ScottHoltzman actually, now I'm getting a Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on Sheets("Stencils").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 8)).Copy

Comment: @Mcodewick Try `Sheets("Stencils").Cells(i,2).Resize(1,7).Copy`

Comment: @jsotola I do have an if statement

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thanks!! That worked. Any explanation as to why that works?

Comment: @Mcodewick - Mainly it has to do with correct syntax. The syntax you had in your last statement was *technically* correct, but again you left `Cells` unqualified, so the compiler most likely got confused. I just created a shorter way to write what you were trying to accomplish. I encourage you to read up on methods I used.